# Zend and data mappers - how to get data from multiple tables

Tags: php, oop, object, zend-framework, datamapper

I am newbie to Data Mappers concept and so far I only used Active Record.

I have following MySQL tables:

**Calendar**

- id
- idEvent
- date

**Events**

- id
- name

I need to fetch names and dates of all events that happened before today.

What's the most efficient structure to archive this? I am getting super confused if I need to create objects for each Calendar entry, and how will I link idEvent from calendar table and id from events table.

Answer (score 0):

In `yourProjectRootFolder/application/Module/models/mappers/CalendarMapper.php` (amend the path as per your directory structure if you're not using the same):

```
<?php

class Module_Model_Mapper_Calendar extends Your_Abstract_Mapper
{
    public function rowToObject($row)
    {
        $calendar = new Module_Model_Calendar();
        $calendar->setDate($row->date);

        if(!empty($row->idEvent))
        {
            $eventMapper = new Module_Model_Mapper_Event();
            $event = $eventMapper->find($row->idEvent);
            $calendar->setEvent($event);
        }


        return $calendar;
    }
```

Now, each time you call `$calendarMapper->find($calendarId);` in your controller, you should be provided with both `Calendar` object with `Event` object linked to it.